# Permission denied error while installing pixiedust jupyter

Tags: installation, jupyter, permission-denied, pixiedust

Team, im getting permission denied error [Errno 13] Permission denied while extracting spark package (2.1.0) in local installation. I have admin access to folders and verified in Security as well. Any pointers will be helpful

**Environment details**

```
OS - **Windows 7**
(C:\conda) C:\conda>conda --version
**conda 4.3.30**
(C:\conda) C:\conda>python --version
**Python 3.6.3 :: Anaconda, Inc.**
(C:\conda) C:\conda>jupyter --version
**4.3.0**
(C:\conda) C:\conda>pip --version
**pip 9.0.1** from C:\conda\lib\site-packages (python 3.6)
```

From anaconda terminal - **jupyter pixiedust install**

```
←[32;1mStep 1: **PIXIEDUST_HOME**: C:\conda\pixiedust-master←[0m
        Keep y/n [y]? **y**

←[32;1mStep 2: **SPARK_HOME**: C:\conda\pixiedust-master\bin\spark←[0m
        Keep y/n [y]? y

←[32;1mDirectory C:\conda\pixiedust-master\bin\spark does not contain a valid SPARK install←[0m
        **Download Spark** y/n [y]? y

←[32;1mWhat version would you like to download? 1.6.3, 2.0.2, 2.1.0, 2.2.0 [2.2.0]: ←[0m**2.1.0**
F 82%
F 100%
```

**Error Details - Below**

> ←[FExtracting Spark 2.1.0 to C:\conda\pixiedust-master\bin\spark
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):    File "c:\conda\lib\runpy.py",
>   line 193, in _run_module_as_main
>       "**main**", mod_spec)
>
> File "c:\conda\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
>       exec(code, run_globals)
>
> File "C:\conda\Scripts\jupyter-pixiedust.EXE__main__.py", line 9,
>   in
>
> File "c:\conda\lib\site-packages\install\pixiedustapp.py", line 41,
>   in main
>       PixiedustJupyterApp.launch_instance()
>
> File "c:\conda\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py",
>   line 657, in launch_instance
>       app.initialize(argv)
>
> File "", line 2, in initialize
>
> File "c:\conda\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py",
>   line 87, in catch_config_error
>       return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "c:\conda\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py",
>   line 296, in initialize
>       self.parse_command_line(argv)
>
> File "", line 2, in parse_command_line
>
> File "c:\conda\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py",
>   line 87, in catch_config_error
>       return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "c:\conda\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py",
>   line 514, in parse_command_line
>       return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)
>
> File "", line 2, in initialize_subcommand
>
> File "c:\conda\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py",
>   line 87, in catch_config_error
>       return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "c:\conda\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py",
>   line 452, in initialize_subcommand
>       self.subapp.initialize(argv)
>
> File "", line 2, in initialize
>
> File "c:\conda\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py",
>   line 87, in catch_config_error
>       return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "c:\conda\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line
>   239, in initialize
>       self.parse_command_line(argv)
>
> File "c:\conda\lib\site-packages\install\createKernel.py", line 150,
>   in parse_command_line
>       self.download_spark(silent, silent_spark_version)
>
> File "c:\conda\lib\site-packages\install\createKernel.py", line 409,
>   in download_spark
>       self.extract_temp_file(temp_file, self.spark_home)
>
> File "c:\conda\lib\site-packages\install\createKernel.py", line 478,
>   in extract_temp_file
>       tar = tarfile.open(temp_file.name, "r:gz")
>
> File "c:\conda\lib\tarfile.py", line 1586, in open
>       return func(name, filemode, fileobj, **kwargs)
>
> File "c:\conda\lib\tarfile.py", line 1633, in gzopen
>       fileobj = gzip.GzipFile(name, mode + "b", compresslevel, fileobj)
>
> File "c:\conda\lib\gzip.py", line 163, in **init**
>       fileobj = self.myfileobj = builtins.open(filename, mode or 'rb')
>
> **PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Temp\tmpnt0i718r.tgz'**

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Windows is not a supported platform by the PixieDust install script as mentioned in the PixieDust site documentation: https://ibm-watson-data-lab.github.io/pixiedust/install.html.
As a workaround I suggest to use a docker container with Linux or MacOS.